# Haskell combine 2 maps into single map after checking their values and making changes

Tags: haskell

I have 2 maps for example: `[("a", "b")]` and `[("b","c"), ("b","d")]` Where the output map will have (x,z) values, if exists such an y, as (x,y) which is in map A and (y,z) which is in map B

So for the above maps `[("a", "b")]` and `[("b","c"), ("b","d")]` the output should be `[("a","c"), ("a","d")]`

How could this be done?

Comment: [(>->)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/relation-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Relation.html#v:-62--45--62-)

Comment: Do you already know list comprehensions? Try to transform your where-clause into a list comprehension!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind (flatmap) the list with all elements in `b` that match:

```hs
map1 :: [(String, String)]
map1 = [("a", "b")]

map2 :: [(String, String)]
map2 = [("b","c"), ("b","d")]

combineMaps :: (Eq b) => [(a, b)] -> [(b, c)] -> [(a, c)]
combineMaps m1 m2 = m1 >>= \(a, b) ->
    map (\(c, d) -> (a, d))
    . filter (\(c, d) -> b == c)
    $ m2

main :: IO ()
main = print $ combineMaps map1 map2 -- [("a","c"), ("a","d")]
```

Comment: Surely you should have something more like `composeMaps :: combineMaps :: Eq b => [(b, c)] -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, c)]`, which is both more general and easier to understand. I can't immediately tell which way the composition goes in your code.

Comment: Then just run `nub` on it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem description can be translated quite literally into a list comprehension:

```
-- The type of association lists
type Assoc a b = [(a, b)]

-- Equivalent to ‘(Eq y) => [(x, y)] -> [(y, z)] -> [(x, z)]’
composeAssocs :: (Eq y) => Assoc x y -> Assoc y z -> Assoc x z

composeAssocs xy yz =  -- The composition of two associations
  [ (x, z)             -- …is the set of all pairs (x, z)
  | (x, y) <- xy       -- …for each pair (x, y) in the first
  , (y', z) <- yz      -- …and each pair (y', z) in the second
  , y == y'            -- …where y = y'.
  ]
```

I use the name `compose` here because this is a composition of *relations*; notice the similarity with the type of `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)` and especially its flipped form (a.k.a. `(>>>)`). (In fact, if it weren’t for the `Eq` constraint, `Assoc` would form a `Category`.)

The list comprehension also has a straightforward equivalent in `do` notation:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

composeAssocs :: (Eq y) => Assoc x y -> Assoc y z -> Assoc x z
composeAssocs xy yz = do
  (x, y) <- xy
  (y', z) <- yz
  guard (y == y')
  pure (x, z)
```

Note however that this isn’t very efficient: it takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) time in the length of the input lists, since for *each* element of the first association, *every* element of the second association will be checked. If you use a more efficient representation such as `Data.Map`, you can achieve better performance, e.g.:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Set (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type Relation a b = Map a (Set b)

composeRelations :: (Ord x, Ord y, Ord z) => Relation x y -> Relation y z -> Relation x z
composeRelations xy yz = Map.fromListWith Set.union
  [ (x, zs)
  | (x, ys) <- Map.toList xy
  , y <- Set.toList ys
  , Just zs <- pure (Map.lookup y yz)
  ]
```

This takes O(n log n) time: linear in the size of the first map to iterate over its range, logarithmic time for each element of the range to `lookup` the result.

Notice that this uses `fromListWith` instead of a plain `fromList` to account for a case like this, where there are branching “paths” from the domain of the first relation to the range of the second relation.

```
relation :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> Relation a b
relation assocs = Map.fromListWith Set.union
  [(k, Set.singleton v) | (k, v) <- assocs]
-- Or:
-- relation = Map.fromListWith Set.union . fmap (fmap Set.singleton)

-- a ─┬─▶ b
--    └─▶ c
-- 
--    +
-- 
-- b ─┬─▶ x
--    └─▶ y
-- c ───▶ z
-- 
-- =
-- 
-- a ─┬─▶ b ─┬─▶ x
--    │      └─▶ y
--    └─▶ c ───▶ z
-- 
-- =
-- 
-- a ─┬─▶ x
--    ├─▶ y
--    └─▶ z

composeRelations
  (relation [("a", "b"), ("a", "c")])
  (relation [("b", "x"), ("b", "y"), ("c", "z")])
  ==
  (relation [("a", "x"), ("a", "y"), ("a", "z")])
```

If we had used `fromList`, later lookups would override earlier ones:

```
composeRelationsWrong :: (Ord x, Ord y) => Relation x y -> Relation y z -> Relation x z
composeRelationsWrong xy yz = Map.fromList
  [ (x, zs)
  | (x, ys) <- Map.toList xy
  , y <- Set.toList ys
  , Just zs <- pure (Map.lookup y yz)
  ]

composeRelationsWrong
  (relation [("a", "b"), ("a", "c")])
  (relation [("b", "x"), ("b", "y"), ("c", "z")])
  == relation [("a", "z")]
```